# Meteor.call not returning a response

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to get Stripe working with the new promises support.

Using checkout, I get the token and send it to the server:

```
Meteor.call('submit_charge', res.id, fee, name, reg, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err, res);
});
```

The server method is defined as:

```
submit_charge: function(tok, amt, name, reg) {
    var Stripe = StripeAPI('privatekey');
    console.log('Submitting charge for ' + name);
    Stripe.charges.create({
        amount: amt,
        currency: "usd",
        card: tok,
        description: "Payment - " + name,
        metadata: {
            'reg': reg
        },
    }).then(function(charge) {
        console.log('Charge: ' + charge.id);
        return charge.id;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return 0;
    });
}
```

I can call the method and it executes, but doesn't return anything. The `console.log(err, res)` in the `Meteor.call` returns undefined for both.

The charge processes... and the console.logs show the charge ID from Stripe, so it doesn't seem to be an async issue.

Am I missing something incredibly basic here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use synchronous javascript:

```
submit_charge: function(tok, amt, name, reg) {
    var Stripe = StripeAPI('privatekey');
    console.log('Submitting charge for ' + name);

    var createCharge = Meteor._wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create.bind(Stripe.charges));

    try {
        var result = createCharge({
            amount: amt,
            currency: "usd",
            card: tok,
            description: "Payment - " + name,
            metadata: {
            'reg': reg
        });

        return result;
    }
    catch(e) {
        //Error
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Basically you're trying to return data from within a callback. You need to `return` data to your meteor method and not the function in the `then`.

Using `Meteor._wrapAsync` uses Fibers to wait until the transaction is complete then returns the value or throws an error (hence the try/catch) to get the error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using a Future to accomplish the same thing.